# How to set sound level and play a sound, using commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, audio

I am working with Windows-10 (probably home edition), and I'd like to do the following (in a batchfile, to be run using task scheduler):

- determine the sound level of the computer (the speaker/headphone is set to a value between 0% and 100%)
- switch that sound level quite high (±90%)
- play a sound
- put the sound level back to its original value.

What are the issues?

- I don't know how to read/set the sound level (I can read it in an interactive way from the taskbar, but I have no idea (basic commandline, `WMIC`, `REG QUERY`) how to do this.
- I can easily choose a program and a file to be opened by that program (like `C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe C:\Temp_Folder\test.txt`), but I have no idea how to do this with a sound file.

In case you say "Oh, in Powershell that's a piece of cake.", that might work too, but I don't know how to launch a Powershell script in the task scheduler.

Can anybody give me a hand here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [View / change sound volume on Windows from command line or GUI](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html#command_line)

Comment: [Play sound from a batch file (Windows) - Real's How-to](https://www.rgagnon.com/gp/gp-playsound-from-batch-file-windows.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill: are you saying that, in order to read or change a basic computer setting, I must install external software, and in order to open a file from a program, I need ActiveX programming???

Comment: Yes to both if you want to do it all from a batch file.